# Making image slider work automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, slider

I have imported a image slider into my webpage. It works fine but doesn't work automatically. I have tried to add some jquery that makes the image change after 4 seconds but for some reason it only works once and goes to the last image in the list. Can someone show me where I am going wrong and help me to make the slider work on its own.

Here is the mark-up...

```
<ul id="body">
<input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-1" checked />
<li id="img-container">
    <div id="img-inner">
        <img src="file:///C:/smilburn/Practices/images/blackscale.jpg">
    </div>
    <label for="img-6" class="sb-bignav" title="Previous">&#x2039;</label>
    <label for="img-2" class="sb-bignav" title="Next">&#x203a;</label>
</li>

<input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-2" />
<li id="img-container">
    <div id="img-inner">
        <img src="file:///C:/smilburn/Practices/images/huf.jpg">
    </div>
    <label for="img-1" class="sb-bignav" title="Previous">&#x2039;</label>
    <label for="img-3" class="sb-bignav" title="Next">&#x203a;</label>
</li>

<input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-3" />
<li id="img-container">
    <div id="img-inner">
        <img src="file:///C:/smilburn/Practices/images/palace.jpg">
    </div>
    <label for="img-2" class="sb-bignav" title="Previous">&#x2039;</label>
    <label for="img-4" class="sb-bignav" title="Next">&#x203a;</label>
</li>

<input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-4" />
<li id="img-container">
    <div id="img-inner">
        <img src="file:///C:/smilburn/Practices/images/skatecafe.jpg">
    </div>
    <label for="img-3" class="sb-bignav" title="Previous">&#x2039;</label>
    <label for="img-5" class="sb-bignav" title="Next">&#x203a;</label>
</li>

<input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-5" />
<li id="img-container">
    <div id="img-inner">
        <img src="file:///C:/smilburn/Practices/images/only.jpg">
    </div>
    <label for="img-4" class="sb-bignav" title="Previous">&#x2039;</label>
    <label for="img-6" class="sb-bignav" title="Next">&#x203a;</label>
</li>
<input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-6" />
<li id="img-container">
    <div id="img-inner">
        <img src="file:///C:/smilburn/Practices/images/supreme.jpg">
    </div>
    <label for="img-5" class="sb-bignav" title="Previous">&#x2039;</label>
    <label for="img-7" class="sb-bignav" title="Next">&#x203a;</label>
</li>
<input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-7" />
<li id="img-container">
    <div id="img-inner">
        <img src="file:///C:/smilburn/Practices/images/adidas.jpg">
    </div>
    <label for="img-6" class="sb-bignav" title="Previous">&#x2039;</label>
    <label for="img-8" class="sb-bignav" title="Next">&#x203a;</label>
</li>
```

Here is the jquery I have added..

```
function gogo(){
    $('label[title="Next"]').click();
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval('gogo()',4000);
});
```

Comment: You can't have those input tags floating about outside of LI tags. A UL or an OL can only contain LI tags with other elements placed within those LI tags. Also you have no closing UL tag.

Comment: Also `click()` doesn't trigger the `click` event, if you want to trigger an event in jquery use `$('label[title="Next"]').trigger('click');`

Comment: I just tried to put them in the LI's and it completely broke it @BillyMoat

Comment: @Milo-J - It may have broken your layout but that just means you have to work out how to fix your layout in a semantically correct way now. What I said above stands, you can't have elements placed where you had them. On another note your LI elements all have the same ID. Ids should be unique. You should use class names instead of those IDs as you can have multiple class names which are the same.

Comment: Just changed that, still no luck @Chris

Comment: Which carousel are you using?

Comment: Just one I found online. Where would I put the input now then? @BillyMoat

Comment: What's the URL of the site you got it from? You also have multiple IDs which are the same as each other called "img-inner" - these should also be classes. I'm not sure where your radio buttons should go because I'm not sure what they are meant to be doing or where they should sit as I can't see a working example.

Comment: It could help if u, mention the slider so one, could at least test a possible solution. Without this information we might be stabbing in the dark.

Comment: Fix your HTML, link to the slider, and consider using a slider that has auto built in. There are at least dozens of them available. No sense reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.. easy to work with slider plugins

http://bxslider.com/

or this

http://rhinoslider.com